# Дублировать строку Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, hotkeys

Как в VS дублировать строку кода, как например в VS Code shift+alt+UP/DOWN или в IDEA по моему ctrl+D. Не могу найти, нет такой функции?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> работает в `VS2017` без дополнительных расширений.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> работает с установленным `Resharper`.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Не очень трудно найти в доках, но все-же: Ctrl+D (vs17)

Comment: Ваш вариант не работает. Я искал документацию и именно о дубле строке не нашел. У меня VS 17.

Comment: @Winteriscoming, прежде чем ставить минус, нужно хотя бы подумать что писал я не просто. Visual Studio 2017 Community, Ctrl+D дубль-строки. Если нужно то даже сделаю гифку

Comment: Не надо гифку. Вы указали, что в доках не очень трудно найти, дайте пожалуйста ссылку.

Comment: @Winteriscoming, http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2017/, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx

Comment: Вы сами-то смотрели свои ссылки? Вероятно, у вас стоит R#.